# Is there a way to share def's between different classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an application with quite a number of classes. The classes have a number of functions as per def's that are common and obviously some that are not.

Is there a way to define the functions that have common function in one place and be available to a number of classes, or do I have to have at least the def's in every class?

Comment: Yes, [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by defining the `func`, which is defined outside.
Then to refer that function in different classes, use the same `func` inside the classes

```
def func():
    print('func')

class B:

    def funcB(self):
        print('funcB')

    def func(self):
        func()

class C:

    def funcC(self):
        print('funcC')

    def func(self):
        func()
```

These can be called now as follows.

```
b = B()
b.func()
#funcA
b.funcB()
#funcB
c = C()
c.func()
#funcA
c.funcC()
#funcC
```

Comment: Check if this helps you?

Comment: Accept - Is that the green tick?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: I saw that you accepted another answer, could you tell me what was missing in my answer so that I can improve it

Comment: Sorry click first tick I saw

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Amadan in the comments, class inheritance is a good and consistent way of sharing class objects. Below is an example:

```
class animals:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def has_legs(self, type):
        if type == "snake":
            print(False)
        else:
            print(True)


class dog(animals):

    def __init__(self):
        # This is where the magic happens
        animals.__init__(self)
        pass

    def dog_has_legs(self):
        self.has_legs("dog")


bofur = dog()
bofur.dog_has_legs()
bofur.has_legs("snake")
```

Result:

```
>>> bofur.dog_has_legs()
True
>>> bofur.has_legs("snake")
False
```

As you can see, the class `dog` inherits from `animals`, and so it can call functions and other objects from the `animals` class as if they belonged to the `dog` class.